# Does Practical NFS Authentication for RPCSEC_GSS Exist Other Than Kerberos?

Tags: security, authentication, nfs

Most of the reading I have done suggests that RPCSEC_GSS can be set up using Kerberos, but we don't already have a Kerberos server set up.  I had read there were other auth methods like LIPKEY that were supposed to be alternative (pluggable?) auth schemes, but I can't seem to find much information on them.

Is RPCSEC_GSS + Kerberos the way to go if I want to move away from AUTH_SYS (aka AUTH_UNIX)?  Or is there something that is a little more secure than AUTH_SYS but not as complex as setting up a Kerberos installation?

Thanks,
Carl

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The kerberos5 is the only RPCSEC_GSS implementatin supported by all OSes. LIPKEY is depricated. There is a x509 implementation as well, pku2u,but it still based on kerberos infrastructure. To make it short, kerberos is the only one which can be used. You can use windows AD as KDC.